# Cordova set up Command to build environments

Tags: ios, cordova, backbone.js, command-line-interface

I currently have a backbone app wrapped up in Cordova. I use the CLI to run cordova build each time I need to check it out on a device. I have a local, staging, and live build of my app each associated with a different endpoint. I was curious if, using the Cordova CLI, I could define something that the app could see and say "I see X variable set, I will use this environment endpoint". Something like...

Cordova Build Live

Does this exist or is it possible to build out?

Thanks